# Scope error with locally abstract type when GADT constructor contains multiple type variables

Tags: types, ocaml, gadt, locally-abstract-type

Given this GADT

```
type _ t = 
  | A : (string -> 'ok) * (string -> 'err) -> ('ok, 'err) result t
```

Why is it that this fails with a "type constructor would escape its scope" error

```
let f (type a) (gadt: a t): a Future.t =
  Future.bind (fetch ()) (fun response ->
      match gadt with
      | A (ok, _) -> Ok (ok response))
```

```
Error: This expression has type $0 but an expression was expected of type 'a
       The type constructor $0 would escape its scope
```

while this, which just extracts the pattern match into a separate function, works?

```
let parse (type a) (gadt: a t) (response: string): a = 
  match gadt with
  | A (ok, _) -> Ok (ok response)
                     
let f (type a) (gadt: a t): a Future.t = 
  Future.bind (fetch ()) (parse gadt)
```

The first example also works with a simpler GADT such as

```
type _ t =
  | B : (string -> 'a) -> 'a t
```

suggesting there is some weird interaction between GADT constructors with multiple type variables, locally abstract types and closures.

This has been tested on several OCaml versions from 4.06 to 4.14 with identical results, so it seems unlikely to be a bug at least.

##### Complete example

```
module Future = struct
  type 'a t

  let bind : 'a t -> ('a -> 'b) -> 'b t = Obj.magic
end
  
let fetch : unit -> 'a Future.t = Obj.magic

type _ t = 
  | A : (string -> 'ok) * (string -> 'err) -> ('ok, 'err) result t
```

```
let parse (type a) (gadt: a t) (response: string): a = 
  match gadt with
  | A (ok, _) -> Ok (ok response)
                     
let f_works (type a) (gadt: a t): a Future.t = 
  Future.bind (fetch ()) (parse gadt)
```

```
let f_fails (type a) (gadt: a t): a Future.t =
  Future.bind (fetch ()) (fun response ->
      match gadt with
      | A (ok, _) -> Ok (ok response))
```

###### Edit: Extended example

The above example is a bit over-simplified, in that while it does illustrate the underlying problem well, it doesn't show that I actually do need the whole `('ok, 'err) result` type to be abstracted, because there are other constructors with other shapes, here illustrated by the additional `B` constructor:

```
type _ t = 
  | A : (string -> 'ok) * (string -> 'err) -> ('ok, 'err) result t
  | B : (string -> 'a) -> 'a t

let f (type a) (gadt: a t): a Future.t =
  Future.bind (fetch ()) (fun response ->
      match gadt with
       | A (ok, _) -> Ok (ok response)
       | B f -> f response)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to see the issue in this case is that

```
let f (type a) (gadt: a t): a Future.t =
  Future.bind (fetch ()) (fun response ->
      match gadt with
      | A (ok, _) -> Ok (ok response)
  )
```

is expecting that the type constraint `a Future.t` is propagated to the argument of the `bind` function at exactly the right time to be used to repack the type `($0,$1) result` into `a`.

This doesn't work out.
The smallest fix is to add the annotation when leaving the pattern matching:

```
let f (type a) (gadt: a t) =
  Future.bind (fetch ()) (fun response ->
      match gadt with
      | A (ok, _) -> (Ok (ok response): a)
  )
```

With this annotation, we are using the local equation `($0,$1) result=a` to make sure that the local types `$0` and `$1` do not escape their branch of the pattern matching.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the timing not working out. Do you mean it depends on the order that the type checker works?

Comment: Also, `(fun response: a -> match gadt with ...)` also works, and is a bit more convenient when there's more branches :)

Comment: It depends on how type information is propagated during the typechecking of the application, and this is mostly an implementation detail of the typechecker (there is also the issue that Future.t is not declared as injective in its parameter).

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a locally abstract type for each type variable to extend its scope, e.g., the following typechecks,

```
let f (type ok err) (gadt: (ok,err) result t): (ok,err) result Future.t =
  Future.bind (fetch ()) (fun response ->
      match gadt with
      | A (ok, _) -> Ok (ok response))
```

In your example, you bind `a` with `('ok,'err) result` and it would be a little bit far-fetching for a compiler to assume that if `a` locally abstract, then `'ok` and `'err` are as well abstract. In other words, you can't abstract two variables with a single variable.

In addition, irrelevant to the scope issue, when you abstract `'a` in `'a t` to `a`, and then unify it with `_ result` by using `Ok (ok response)` you break the abstraction of `a`.

```
let f (type a) (gadt: a t): a Future.t =
  Future.bind (fetch ()) (fun response ->
      match gadt with
      | A (ok, err) ->
        Ok (ok response))
```

This is indicated by the error message that you decided to ignore,

```
Type ('a, 'b) result is not compatible with type a
```

The type variable of `'a t` is shared across all branches of GADT and the fact that is constrained in the branch `A` to `('ok,'error) result` doesn't mean that all instances of `'a t` constrained to it, even though your type definition has only one branch at this time.

For what it's worth, although it is possible that your example is just a minimization to highlight the problem, but the same behavior could be achieved without any GADT and scope issues using a simple ADT, e.g.,

```
  type 'a t = {
    ok : string -> 'ok;
    err : string -> 'err;
  } constraint 'a = ('ok,'err) result

  let f {ok; err} =
    Future.bind (fetch ()) (fun response ->
        Ok (ok response))
```

Comment: Sorry, I did oversimplify the example a bit. I've updated the question with an example showing that there are other constructors with other shapes, so that using two locally abstract types unfortunately isn't possible. I'm also not getting the error you say I've ignored, in any version I've tried, and I'm not getting an error with the ADT example either. It also seems that the `parse`/`f_works` example, and @octachron's answer, contradicts your explanation. But perhaps it applies to some version prior to 4.06?

Comment: It's great that you have updated the answer as it is now an excellent example showing that sometimes we need more abstract constraints. I am not sure why you're not getting the other error, I am using 4.13.1 but checking with merlin, it could be that you're using the compiler only, which will pick only of the errors. My answer doesn't contradict @octachron's, by unifying `($0,$1) result` with `a` on the branch level we prevent the abstraction leak. But I am surprised that annotating the return type of the function (as you suggested) works for the double-branch version. That's neat!

Comment: Hmm, yeah I can see how it's not contradictory, just missing a piece of the puzzle. And I've just been testing with `utop` and a couple of online repls. I can see how merlin's error recovery would have been helpful here. Thanks for the explanation!